# How to fix 'Incovertible types' in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

## Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

```
package com.dhami.ajay.nearby;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

## This line is giving me incompatible type issues:

```
_SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)_
```

Comment: Add your code snippet, there is no enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @Ikazuchi I have now added code where I am getting issue

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting means that the fragment with the id "map" is defined as a regular fragment. It could be that your fragment is missing `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` in the layout. Check to make sure that your XML layout contains something like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

---

Side Note:

It looks like you are using the [Tutorial for the Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start) provided by Google. By default, the `res/layout/activity_maps.xml` should have that exact fragment block in it, so you shouldn't have any issues unless you modified the layout or implemented your own.